# Fluid focus between text fields and tinymce in jQuery UI Dialog in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, firefox, tinymce

I have a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4MtkP/2/) to show this.

Steps to reproduce the problem:

- First, click the button to launch a jQuery Dialog.
- Then once the tinyMCE editor loads, click in a text field and then
  into the tinyMCE editor.
- Now click in a different text field.

**Notice that the text field that was previously focused gets focus back and not the field that is clicked.  This does not happen in `Safari` but does happen in `Firefox`.  This only happens if the dialog is a modal dialog.**

Any help in getting around this issue would be great.

The code for the button:

```
 $('#button').
    on('click', function() {
      $('#diag').dialog({
        modal: true,
        open: function() {
           tinymce.init({
                selector: "textarea"
           });
        }
      });
    });
```

UPDATE:
I found that this is happening in the call to _focusTabble.  Is this because Firefox does not support the focusin event?  [Add support for DOM 3 Focusin](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=687787)